# Type not inferred correctly in generic function with key and value as args

Tags: typescript

I have a type MyMap with 2 different keys that take an array of callbacks with different signatures.

```js
type MyMap = {
   type1: (() => void)[] 
   type2: ((data: string) => void)[]
}
```

I want to create a generic function that takes a key and a callback, and add it to an object of type MyMap.

```js
const map: MyMap = { type1: [], type2: [] };

function addToMap<T extends keyof MyMap>(k: T,  cb: MyMap[T][number]): void {
        map[k].push(cb);
}
```

TypeScript shows me the error when i try to push the callback in the array:

```
Argument of type '(() => void) | ((data: string) => void)' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.
  Type '(data: string) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
    Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 1 or more, but got 0.(2345)
```

Is there a way to make TypeScript understand that the callback I provided is the right one for the key?

Comment: The recommended approach is described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and for your code example it looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nnorxm). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: it's working, although not ideal as i have to change my original type and remove the arrays. I'll use your solution as a last resort in case there is nothing that can be done. But I'm really interested in an explanation if you have the time. Thanks

Comment: You don’t have to change the type but you will have to compute the type I used from it. I’ll show an alternative when I get a chance (but it’s essentially the same approach). Not sure why you prefer the original type though, if TS doesn’t understand it.  Will be back in a bit

Comment: How about [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Wkq6LN). I left your type and your `map` alone, although I had to compute the other versions in order for the compiler to understand what you're doing. Shall I write up an answer using this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't "see" the fact that every member of `MyMap` with key `K` is an array that allows you to `push` a value of type `MyMap[K][number]` onto it. It can verify the for an *individual* `K`, but when `K` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), it doesn't know how.  It lacks the ability to automatically convert a list of facts into a single generality.  So it doesn't see `map[k].push` as a single coherent method; instead it sees it as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of methods, and any correlation between `map[k]` and `cb` is lost.

---

If you want the compiler to follow your logic, you'll need to explicitly represent the operations in terms of such a generality. The recommended approach is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Starting from your `MyMap` type,

```
type MyMap = {
  type1: (() => void)[]
  type2: ((data: string) => void)[]
}
const map: MyMap = { type1: [], type2: [] };
```

we can create the "base" version of the type, corresponding to just the elements of the arrays:

```
type MyMapBase = { [K in keyof MyMap]: MyMap[K][number] }
    
/* type MyMapBase = {
    type1: () => void;
    type2: (data: string) => void;
} */
```

And then we can write `addToMap()` as a generic function operating on `MyMapBase` explicitly:

```
function addToMap<K extends keyof MyMap>(k: K, cb: MyMapBase[K]): void {
  const m: { [K in keyof MyMap]: MyMapBase[K][] } = map;
  m[k].push(cb);
}
```

Here, we've just assigned `map` to a variable `m` of the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{[K in keyof MyMap]: MyMapBase[K][]}`.  The compiler is happy with the assignment because it has to verify each property individually, and it works.  But now `m` is written explicitly as a type that abstracts over `MyMapBase` generically.  So `m[k]` is of the single generic type `MyMapBase[K][]`. And as such, you can easily `push()` a value of type `MyMapBase[K]` onto it.

---

Note that this would be a lot more straightforward looking if we just *started* with `MyMapBase` in the first place, since that's the actual underlying type that your abstracting over. But if you already have `MyMap` defined somewhere, the code here shows you can still compute the required things from it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiMEMxQLxQN4FgBQUqkgEYAuKACjIEpUA+KANwHsBLAE0oG0BdHPAiAEykKrBMASkAzsABOzAHYBzaijpM2nHtgC+OHP1jwkAIQSToadFA4BpKAqgBrCCEYAzQ4jBdScL7a4OeQBXAFsAIwgZLihdbAB6ACp8cGg-EzMLDF48FKJhFTUWVgBuHL5UoXJRcSlZBWVaBmKynShE+L1sAGNGeWkoUKRfI2RLPIgSay4AGgmq7ljWnDdg+W7gZj6ocIRWABVGLwAeOwgAD2AIeVZJJxd3TyQaMkdSGznu8JH-G0CQiJRLiUUjqVjZXCDJAcRxcAB0YGCkgAFmQvpRWnEVmsNlt5FA9gcjkhTlALlcbndnK4POkwC83lAPlAvj8MuYAiDmmwIXhev1gINSFZbPZ8dTHnSfE8wKYOX9FtpUFCwK08KEYfDESi0eEMTg4kA)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that never be the case when you call function with wrong `key`/`cb` pair type like `addToMap("type1", (data) =>...);` You can simply use type assertion:

```
map[k].push(cb as any);
```

Comment: i prefer to avoid "as any" because it might hide some real errors in my code